# Drawing on JPanel with paint(Graphics gr)

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jpanel, paint

I tried to draw a simple rectangle on a JPanel wich is on a JFrame, but it didn't work. Can someone please give me some advices? Would be happy if someone could... I really tried hard, but I couldn figure out how to do this. This code is part of my "Snake" -program. All the rest works, in excep of this. Here is my Code:

```
package initialising_Package;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.awt.event.WindowListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSlider;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class Initialising extends JPanel implements WindowListener,
        ItemListener, ChangeListener, Runnable {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    private String name;
    private JFrame frame;
    private boolean fall = false;
    private JSlider slider;
    private JLabel lbl1, lbl2, lbl3, lbl4;
    private JComboBox box1, box2, box3;
    private String[] positionsx, positionsy, laenge;
    private JPanel pnl1, pnl2, pnl3, pnlpnl;
    private JButton btn;
    private int beginningLenght, posX, posY;
    private boolean start = false;

    public Initialising() {
        initStartFrame("Initialising");
    }

    public void initStartFrame(String name) {
        frame = new JFrame(name);
        frame.setLocation(300, 300);
        frame.setSize(500, 350);
        frame.setUndecorated(false);
        frame.getContentPane().setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 1));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.addWindowListener(this);

        // GUI
        slider = new JSlider(1, 100, 50);
        slider.addChangeListener(this);
        slider.setPaintTicks(false);
        slider.setPaintTrack(true);

        positionsx = new String[50];
        positionsy = new String[50];
        for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 50; i++, j = j + 10) {
            positionsx[i] = new String("" + j);
            positionsy[i] = new String("" + j);
        }

        laenge = new String[45];
        for (int i = 0; i < 45; i++) {
            laenge[i] = "" + (i + 1);
        }

        box1 = new JComboBox(positionsx);
        box1.addItemListener(this);
        box2 = new JComboBox(positionsy);
        box2.addItemListener(this);
        box3 = new JComboBox(laenge);
        box3.addItemListener(this);

        lbl1 = new JLabel("Geschwindigkeit: ");
        lbl2 = new JLabel("Startlaenge: ");
        lbl3 = new JLabel("Position: ");
        pnlpnl = new JPanel();
        pnlpnl.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(95, 490));
        pnlpnl.setBackground(Color.BLACK);

        pnl1 = new JPanel();
        pnl1.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        pnl2 = new JPanel();
        pnl2.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        pnl3 = new JPanel();
        pnl3.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 3));

        btn = new JButton("Snake!");
        btn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(80, 490));

        pnl1.add(lbl1);
        pnl1.add(slider);
        pnl2.add(lbl2);
        pnl2.add(box3);
        pnl3.add(lbl3);
        pnl3.add(box1);
        pnl3.add(box2);

        frame.add(pnlpnl);
        frame.add(pnl1);
        frame.add(pnl2);
        frame.add(pnl3);
        frame.add(btn);

        // GUI

        frame.validate();
        frame.repaint();

    }

    public int getSpeed() {
        return slider.getValue();
    }

    public int getBeginningLenght() {
        return beginningLenght;
    }

    public int getPosX() {
        return posX;
    }

    public int getPosY() {
        return posY;
    }

    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowClosing(WindowEvent arg0) {
        int z = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame,
                "Willst du wirklich benden?", "Warnung", 0);
        if (z == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            System.exit(0);
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeactivated(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowDeiconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowIconified(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void windowOpened(WindowEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Initialising init = new Initialising();
        new Thread(init).start();

    }

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e.getSource().equals(box1)) {
            posX = Integer.parseInt((String) box1.getSelectedItem());
            System.out.println("PosX: " + posX);

        } else if (e.getSource().equals(box2)) {
            posY = Integer.parseInt((String) box2.getSelectedItem());
            System.out.println("PosY: " + posY);

        } else if (e.getSource().equals(box3)) {
            beginningLenght = Integer.parseInt((String) box3.getSelectedItem());
            System.out.println("Beginning Lenght: " + beginningLenght);

            System.out.println("H: " + pnlpnl.getHeight() + " B: "
                    + pnlpnl.getWidth());

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (e.getSource().equals(slider)) {
            System.out.println("Speed: " + slider.getValue());
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
        super.paint(gr);
        gr.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        gr.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        while (true) {
            System.out.println("It works!!");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(800);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            if (!start) {

            }
            repaint();
            validate();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: If this is not the shortest code example that has the problem(I haven't read it), then you will have better luck getting an answer with a shorter example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the paintComponent from the JFrame. That did also call super.paint i.o. super.paintComponent.

```
    pnlpnl = new JPanel() {

        @Override
        public void paintComponent(Graphics gr) {
            super.paintComponent(gr);
            gr.setColor(Color.CYAN);
            gr.fillRect(0, 0, 200, 200);
        }
    };
```

In this paintComponent you can use the JFrame's fields.

As initStartFrame is called in the constructor it should not be overridable (the child class's version then would be called, without the child class being entirely initialized).

```
//Sometimes: public final void initStartFrame(String name) {
private void initStartFrame(String name) {
```

Start the frame as such:

```
    // GUI

    frame.validate();
    //frame.repaint();

    frame.pack();
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you, but unfortunately this doesn't work's for me... If I do what you do I only get a plain window...

Comment: EDIT:
I changed and played around with some things, and now your Idea works! Thank you verry much!